# Access outer class object in a nested class

Tags: java

Is the following code the legit way to access an outer class object inside an inner class? Thanks

```
Class A{
A self;
public A(){
this.self=self;
}
public void test(){}


 Class B{
   public void test2(){
   self.test();
}
 } 
}
```

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: That's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the 'self' reference; just `test();` will get the job done.

inner classes that aren't marked `static` have a secret invisible field of the outer class's type (so, in your example, `A`), and it is the first parameter of the constructor. When you invoke `new B()` in a context where some variant of `this` would refer to an instance of A, then that's silently injected. If no such 'this' is available, then `new B()` is illegal and will not compile; the syntax to pass the secret param is `someInstanceOfA.new B()` in that case.

Any method invocation anywhere in java that isn't qualified (so just `foo()`, vs `something.foo()`) will first check if it makes sense on `this`, and if it doesn't, if it makes sense on any of these secret fields.

Add that together and:

- B has an invisible field of type A.
- `test()` would be an unqualified call, and B() itself does not have a `test()` method, tehrefore, `thatInvisibleField.test()` is how it works.

NB: Your code is not 'clearer', in the sense that your code *also* uses the invisible field: that `self` is getting the same treatment, and ends up resolving to `thatInvisibleInstanceOfA.self` in other to make sense.

NB2: As a general rule of thumb, inner classes should be marked `static`, even if you need stuff from your outer: Then make that invisible field explicit (make an actual `private final A a;` field, and set it in B's constructor) - non-static inner classes are surprising, and that hidden field leads to issues. For example, any instance of B that's still active will prevent garbage collection of A, even if your inner class doesn't use that instance whatsoever. Use non-static inner classes only if you really know what you're doing and it truly makes sense (it rarely does).

Comment: Thanks, and I assume it is invoked on the right object? Thanks

Comment: Well, if your `B` also has a `test()` method, it would run that one, but as long as it doesn't, javac will presume the only one that 'works', with is `A`. In the shadowing case (where both B and A have this method), `A.this.test()` will do it.